# React, adding an animation when removing a class from an element?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a button that is initially transparent. When it is pressed, I want it to "grow" into a coloured circle by passing in a prop that is either "b" or "w". If it is not pressed yet, it should remain transparent. In addition, a button being black or white cannot be predetermined. I also want it to "shrink" back into transparency when that prop becomes null. The grow part is working fine for me, but the shrinking is not.

The button checks the value of the prop and decides which classes to apply:

```
render() {
    var areaClass = classnames({
        button: true,
        black: this.props.gameState === "b",
        white: this.props.gameState === "w",
    })
    return (
      <button className={areaClass} onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}></button>
    );
  }
```

In the CSS, I use a grow keyframe when adding the black and white classes which does the animation properly. I tried putting a shrink keyframe in the button class, but it is not applying the animation when I remove the black or white class. It is just blinking out, as if there was no animation.

```
button {
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  animation-name: shrink;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
}

.button:focus {
  outline: none;
} 

.black, .white {
  animation-name: grow;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
}

.black {
    background: black;
}

.white {
    background: white;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

@keyframes grow {
  0% {transform: scale(0, 0);}
  100% {transform: scale(1, 1);}
}

@keyframes shrink {
  0% {transform: scale(1, 1);}
  100% {transform: scale(0, 0);}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't in React or in the animation, in fact your buttons are shrinking like you expect. However, your `black` and `white` class names are the ones that define the background colors of the buttons, and they are the class names getting removed. Your buttons are shrinking, but they're transparent.

Keep the background-colors defined at all times and assign the `grow` animation with a different class name. Also, apply `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` to make the buttons stay in the end state of the animation.

```
.btn {
  /* other styles */
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.grow {
  animation-name: grow;
}

.black {
    background: black;
}

.white {
    background: white;
    border: 2px solid black;
}:
```

Working fiddle with the changes: https://jsfiddle.net/ssorallen/1dL2wkaq/

Comment: Sorry, I accepted this too early. I edited the question to be more clear, but I don't want the button to initially have the grow class. Also, a button being black or white is not decided by me so I can't really keep the black and white classes always active. Is it still possible after these adjustments?